# How does the browser work with multi-embedded files?

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I've a little question on how the browser is working with files, that are embbeded a few times? Does the browser just work with it one time or often?

I've got some code, that is like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
...
...
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I know, that this isn't the best code, but I want to know how it behaves on the browser performance? Does it load the first jQuery, read and work with it and than again or ignores it the second one?

Regards,
Markus

Comment: They're just all included in the order they appear, just as if the code was written directly in a script tag. This is why you shouldn't include the same library more than once, it can cause issues.

Comment: It's not my code and I just got it to review it ;-) As I wrote, I know that it isn't the best way to include it, but how does it behave an the performance?

Comment: How do you think it behaves? Again, it's like writing the entire jQuery library twice in a script tag, it does have some performance issues, but the more pressing issue is that including all the functions from jQuery twice can cause things to not work correctly.